# _dyld_start causing leaks in iphone apps

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, memory-management, instruments

Using the Allocations Instrument on my Iphone Device, I notice in my heapshots that all my heap growth is caused by the _dyld_start caller (of dyld library).

Here is an example:

```
Snapshot: UIImageView
Heap Growth: 4.83 Kb
Still Alive: 103
```

When I look in the details, all I see is several instances of the following:

```
Object Add: xxxx
Creation Time: ....
Live: check
Responsible Library: dyld
Responsible Caller: _dyld_start
```

1. What does this mean?
2. How can I change my code to release this memory?

Answer (score 0):

if you load your UIImage with imageNamed: then you cant release this.

cause imageNamed: caches the image till the application closes.

you may try to load ur Image with imageWithContentsOfFile: or imageWithData:

Hope that helps